# How to add default collapse to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to edit another designer's jquery collapsiblePanel plugin. How would I add a default collapse? When I load the html in my browser, the first panel is open by default and the rest or any others added are closed. Ideally, I would like the first panel to be closed by default also. I have added other sections of code that I think relate to the JS. 
But honestly some of this is greek to me. Thank you for your time and assistance.

---

**Here's the js...**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
            // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
            return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);


function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-widget");

    // Check if there are any child elements, if not then wrap the inner text within a new  div.
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>");
    }    

    // Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='collapsibleContainerContent ui-widget-content'></div>");

    // Create a new div as the first item within the container.  Put the title of the panel in here.
    $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle ui-widget-header'><div>" +  $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));

    // Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new title div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);
}


function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    // The item clicked is the title div... get this parent (the overall container) and  
    toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}
```

---

**Here is the script as I see it inside the HTML head...**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--// Collapsible Program Content //-->


    var TINY={};


     function T$(i){return document.getElementById(i)}
     function T$$(e,p){return p.getElementsByTagName(e)}

    TINY.accordion=function(){

function slider(n){this.n=n; this.a=[]}
slider.prototype.init=function(t,e,m,o,k){

    var a=T$(t), i=s=0, n=a.childNodes, l=n.length; this.s=k||0; this.m=m||0;
    for(i;i<l;i++){
        var v=n[i];
        if(v.nodeType!=3){
            this.a[s]={}; this.a[s].h=h=T$$(e,v)[0]; 
    this.a[s].c=c=T$$('div',v)[0]; h.onclick=new Function(this.n+'.pr(0,'+s+')');
            if(o==s){h.className=this.s; c.style.height='auto'; 
    c.d=1}else{c.style.height=0; c.d=-1} s++
        }
    }
    this.l=s
};

slider.prototype.pr=function(f,d){
    for(var i=0;i<this.l;i++){
        var h=this.a[i].h, c=this.a[i].c, k=c.style.height; k=k=='auto'? 
 1:parseInt(k); clearInterval(c.t);
        if((k!=1&&c.d==-1)&&(f==1||i==d)){
            c.style.height=''; c.m=c.offsetHeight; 
 c.style.height=k+'px'; c.d=1; h.className=this.s; su(c,1)
        }else if(k>0&&(f==-1||this.m||i==d)){
            c.d=-1; h.className=''; su(c,-1)
        }
    }
};

function su(c){c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c)},20)};
function sl(c){
    var h=c.offsetHeight, d=c.d==1?c.m-h:h; c.style.height=h+ 
(Math.ceil(d/5)*c.d)+'px';
    c.style.opacity=h/c.m; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+h*100/c.m+')';
    if((c.d==1&&h>=c.m)||(c.d!=1&&h==1)){if(c.d==1){c.style.height='auto'}   
clearInterval(c.t)}
};
return{slider:slider}
}();

</script>
```

---

**Here is the JS at the bottom of the page...**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");
parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0,0);
</script>
```

---

**Here is the CSS as it relates to the Collapsible Content...**

/* --------------------------------------Collapsible Program Content---------------------------------*/
       .collapsibleContainer{
        border: solid 1px #9BB5C1;
    font-size: 12px;
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0;

```
   }
  .collapsibleContainer:hover{
    background-color:#efefef;
background-image:url(images/arrows_down.gif);
background-position:503px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color:#71b217;
  }

  .collapsibleContainerTitle{
   font:14px;
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
color:233e8d;

}

.collapsibleContainerTitle div{
padding-top:5px;
padding-left:10px;
color:233e8d;
}
```

.collapsibleContainerContent{
    padding: 10px;

```
}
```

Comment: If using `accordion` from *jQueryUI*, just set `active option` to **false**: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Comment: @Dom he definitely is not using the accordion widget.

Comment: @KevinB hoping he would convert :-D

Comment: The problem with the accordion widget is it doesn't allow multiple panels open at a time. A custom widget like this fixes that

Comment: Can you show what code is being used to initialize this plugin? The first one being open by default is not done by the code above.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle? This plugin can be interesting

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have added other bits of code to my question to help someone with more experience see what may happen.

Comment: I just added the script which sits at the bottom of the HTML page which I think relates to the accordion widget.

Answer (score 0):

This may help! You need to slide it up on load.

```
function($) {
$.fn.extend({
    collapsiblePanel: function() {
    // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
    return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
}


});

$(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideUp();
})(jQuery);
```